# Call to_json on multiple columns using Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

Say I have the following table schema in Postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE users (id text, email text, phone_number text);
```

And I, for whatever reason, want to select the email and the phone number as JSON:

```
SELECT to_json(users.email, users.phone_number) AS user FROM users WHERE id=usr_123;
```

I get an error that looks like this:

```
function to_json(text, text) does not exist 

No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

But this works just fine:

```
SELECT to_json(users.*) AS user FROM users WHERE id=usr_123;
```

How can I select just a few columns (not all of them) using a `to_json` call in Postgres?

Comment: 8 years later, but the accepted answer over here actually worked, and seems to have been 1 year earlier than the question ;) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27732/set-names-to-attributes-when-creating-json-with-row-to-json

Answer (score 5):

The [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) says that `to_json`'s signature is:

```
to_json(anyelement)
```

so you're supposed say `to_json(one_single_value)`. When you say:

```
to_json(users.email, users.phone_number)
```

you're trying to call `to_json` with two values and there is no such `to_json` function. When you say:

```
to_json(user.*)
```

you're actually calling `to_json` with a single `ROW` argument so it works just fine.

You can use a derived table or CTE as [klin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32674223/479863) suggests or you can build the `ROW`s by hand:

```
select to_json(row(users.email, users.phone_number)) ...
```

The problem with this is that that `ROW` won't have any column names so your JSON will use useless keys like `"f1"` and `"f2"`. To get around that you need to cast the `ROW` to something that does have names. One way to get some names is to [create a custom type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html):

```
create type email_and_phone_number as (
    email text,
    phone_number text
)
```

and then cast your `ROW` to that type:

```
select to_json(row(users.email, users.phone_number)::email_and_phone_number) ...
```

You could also use a temporary table instead of a custom type:

```
create temporary table email_and_phone_number (
    email text,
    phone_number text
)
```

and then use the same cast as with a custom type.

If you're building this specific JSON format a lot then a custom type would make sense. If this is a one-off then a temporary table would make sense, the temporary table will automatically disappear when the session ends so there's nothing to clean up. Of course, a derived table or CTE might also make sense depending on the query and what tools you're using to interface with your database.

Answer (score 4):

Use a subquery, e.g.:

```
select to_json(sub)
from (
    select email, phone_number
    from users
    where id = 'usr_123'
    ) sub;
```

or `with` query:

```
with cte as (
    select email, phone_number
    from users
    where id = 'usr_123')
select to_json(cte)
from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove one specific field from the result there is an elegant solution:

```sql
SELECT to_json(users)::jsonb - 'id' AS user FROM users WHERE id=usr_123;
```